# Should I use CoffeeScript soaks and the existential operator together?

Tags: javascript, operators, coffeescript, javascript-objects

I'm working on a script that accepts a `settings` object, but uses default values where settings are not provided.

I just wrote the following line of CoffeeScript:

```
iframe_width = settings?.iframe?.width? ? $iframe_body.width()
```

My intent, in plain English, is:

> If the `settings` object is defined, and it defines a property `iframe`, and the `iframe` property defines a property `width`, then assign the value of the latter property to the variable `iframe_width`. Otherwise, assign the value returned by calling `$iframe_body.width()`.

Does my CoffeeScript code reflect my intent, and is it the most effective way to express that? It seems awkward with all of the existential operators (`?`), so I wanted to put it out there for some feedback (the compiled JavaScript is very terse and cryptic, so it's hard to tell if should work as intended).

Also, I'm not sure whether there's any redundancy in using both the standard existential operator (`?`) and its accessor variant (`?.`) together.

Thanks!

---

**Update:**

The code above doesn't seem to work as expected; however, this does:

```
iframe_width = settings?.iframe?.width ? $iframe_body.width()
```

That makes sense, since I don't think the former code actually accesses the `width` property, but rather just checks for its existence (twice, even?). In this code, I removed the `?` just after the `width` property, since I think that's redundant with the `?` operator between the two expressions. Does that seem correct?

Comment: try it and see what happens :)

Comment: @JasonMiesionczek: Fair enough, but there are often "gotchas" that are hard to spot without a careful code reading, perhaps especially with a language like JavaScript. It might have worked for my test cases, but failed in other cases (note the one that Trevor pointed out in his answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(**Note**: This answer was written before the question was updated. As the questioner realized, `foo? ? bar` isn't just redundant—it actually won't work, because `foo?` evaluates to `true` or `false`, and is therefore always non-null.)

You have two good options for simplifying this: One, you could replace the existential binary operator with an `or`:

```
iframe_width = settings?.iframe?.width? or $iframe_body.width()
```

Two, you could ditch the `?` after `width`—it's redundant:

```
iframe_width = settings?.iframe?.width ? $iframe_body.width()
```

Now, you could do both *if and only if* `iframe.width` will never be `0` (since `0 or x` is `x`). If you can be sure of that, go ahead and make it

```
iframe_width = settings?.iframe?.width or $iframe_body.width()
```

Comment: Gotcha - good explanation. I think it's more clear to me now. Thanks, Trevor!